# What's the best way to get rid of specific parameter from url string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, url-parameters

I have URL string like:

"http://www.xyz/path?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3".

I need to remove only the param2 parameter, so the result should be:

"http://www.xyz/path?param1=value1&param3=value3".

I have done it this way:

```
private String removeParameter(String url, String key) {

      String newParams = "";
      String[] urlArray = url.split("\\?");
      String[] params = urlArray[1].split("&");

      for (String param: params) {

          if (param.contains(key))
              continue;
          else {
              if (newParams != "")
                  newParams = newParams.concat("&");
              newParams = newParams.concat(param);
          }
      }

      return urlArray[0].concat("?").concat(newParams);
  }

    System.out.println("Modified URL: " + removeParameter("http://www.xyz/path?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3", "param2"));
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```java
String url = "http://www.xyz/path?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
String r = url.replaceFirst( "param2=[^&]*(&|$)", "" );
```

**Edit (after Alex's comment):**
Changed the pattern above to include the parameter if it comes at the end. Also, if it is necessary to remove the last trailing `&` in that scenario, you may use this instead of the 2nd line above.

```java
String r = url.replaceAll( "param2=[^&]*(&|$)", "" ).replaceFirst( "&$", "" );
```

The first pattern works like this:

- It first searches for the known param name, `param2` in this case
- Then matches further till the next `&` or the end of string
- Replaces the matched region with an empty string

The second pattern searches for any `&` at the end of the string and replaces with empty string.

Notice that I have used `String.replaceFirst( String, String )`. So, if you think that the parameter may repeat in the query string, you may want to use `String.replaceAll( String, String )` instead.

Comment: this will work for every parameter but not the last one since the url doesn't end with &

Comment: @Álex, thanks. Good observation. I have made an edit. However, it will retain the last `&` if the parameter appears at the end, which technically is OK but not elegant.

Comment: Nice edit! It seems to be working just fine now :)